# How to copy structure of one table to another with foreign key constraints in psql?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, plpgsql, create-table

Foreign key constraints are not copied when using

```
create table table_name ( like source_table INCLUDING ALL)'
```

in Postgres. How can I create a copy of an existing table including all foreign keys.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no option to automatically create foreign keys in `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...`.

For [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html)

> LIKE source_table [ like_option ... ]
>
> Not-null constraints are always copied to the new table. CHECK
>   constraints will be copied only if INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS is specified [...]
>
> Indexes, PRIMARY KEY, and UNIQUE constraints on the original table
>   will be created on the new table only if the INCLUDING INDEXES clause
>   is specified.

In practice it's easy with GUI tools. For example, in PgAdmin III:

- copy declaration (DDL) of `source_table` to query tool (ctrl-e),
- edit the declaration,
- execute sql.

---

In an SQL script you can use the following function. Important assumption: source table foreign keys have correct names i.e. their names contain source table name (what is a typical situation).

```
create or replace function create_table_like(source_table text, new_table text)
returns void language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    execute format(
        'create table %s (like %s including all)',
        new_table, source_table);
    for rec in
        select oid, conname
        from pg_constraint
        where contype = 'f' 
        and conrelid = source_table::regclass
    loop
        execute format(
            'alter table %s add constraint %s %s',
            new_table,
            replace(rec.conname, source_table, new_table),
            pg_get_constraintdef(rec.oid));
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Example of use:

```
create table base_table (base_id int primary key);
create table source_table (id int primary key, base_id int references base_table);

select create_table_like('source_table', 'new_table');

\d new_table

   Table "public.new_table"
 Column  |  Type   | Modifiers 
---------+---------+-----------
 id      | integer | not null
 base_id | integer | 
Indexes:
    "new_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "new_table_base_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (base_id) REFERENCES base_table(base_id)
```

Comment: This is a very helpful function. It wasn't originally specified but one thing this doesn't include is Triggers from the original table. I did run it and can confirm it copies over FK constraints which is not included currently in the (LIKE INCLUDING ALL) options.

Answer (score -1):

One more way is to dump the table structure, change it's name in dump, and load it again:

```
pg_dump -s -t old databases | sed 's/old/new/g' | psql
```

Comment: The question is possibly to create a table form already existing table with same schema and constraints form sql.

Comment: `pg_dump -s -t old databases` will not contain the foreign key constraints