# Faster way to copy a large PostgreSQL table into a new table with Ruby on Rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, database-migration, rails-migrations

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project with a PostgreSQL database, and I have a large table with millions of records. I want to copy this table into another table named new_X. I want both tables to be identical at the end. By identical I mean, the same constraints & default values. Also the primary key in the old table is (id). And I want new_X to have the same auto-incrementing primary key.
I have two approaches;

## Approach 1: Copy the table and then add the constraints and indexes

First copying the values to the new table, and creating a sequence for the id, and then adding the not null constraints and default values.

```
# Copy the old table to new table
execute <<-SQL.squish
  CREATE TABLE new_X AS TABLE old_X;
SQL

# Create a new serial sequence for id
execute <<-SQL.squish
  CREATE SEQUENCE new_X_id_seq;
SQL

# Update the id column to use the new sequence
execute <<-SQL.squish
  ALTER TABLE new_X
  ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('new_X_id_seq');
SQL

# Set the sequences current value to the maximum existing id value
execute <<-SQL.squish
  SELECT setval('new_X_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM new_X));
SQL

# Set the id column as the primary key
execute <<-SQL.squish
  ALTER TABLE new_X
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
SQL
```

After creating the table and adding the records, now I'll add the constraints, default values and indexes. For example I'll have to add this not null constraint. And the index.

```
# Add the created_at and updated_at columns with NOT NULL constraint
execute <<-SQL.squish
  ALTER TABLE new_X
  ADD COLUMN created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  ADD COLUMN updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
SQL
```

Now add the index.

```
# Add index for is_Y
execute <<-SQL.squish      
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY index_new_X_on_is_Y
  ON new_X (is_Y);
SQL
```

## Create the table with column names, constraints, defaults, indexes and then insert the data

Create a table with name new_X. With all the column names, constraints, defaults, indexes. After creating it, insert millions of records from the old table.

I think I'm closer to approach #1, but I would appreciate any insights, best practices, or experiences from the community in dealing with similar scenarios. Thank you!

Since I don't have millions of records in my development environment, I couldn't test the behaviours.

Comment: The following might work for you. You can use `CREATE TABLE new_X (LIKE old_x INCLUDING ALL)` to copy all of the  column names, constraints, defaults, indexes. Then `INSERT INTO new_x OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE SELECT * FROM old_x` to insert all the data. This will keep your constraints, indexes, identity sequences etc. intact and should move all the existing data as is.

Comment: @engineersmnky looks like FK constraint [is not included](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23693873/10608621) in the `INCLUDING ALL`

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for the answer! It worked in my development DB. Are there any performance difference between CREATE TABLE new_X AS TABLE old_X; and your suggestion ? And I want to investigate further about the foreign keys. Could you provide me a document or some links about this ?

Comment: you mention that you can't test this in your dev database. I would definitely not do this in production without testing it in development first. I suggest dumping your production database and loading the data into your dev environment. I do this regularly if I think there's a production issue that is data-related, or else to test performance tweaks.

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68098793/rails-copy-a-table-from-one-schema-to-another-schema-in-same-database ????